# First and Last value in Group in PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to figure out how to return the first and last values of each group in PowerBI Dax.

I've tried firstnonblank, I don't have the formula for that one anymore though and also tried the formula below

```
OpenSpeed = CALCULATE (
    MAX ( statcastdetails[release_speed] ),
    FILTER ( statcastdetails, statcastdetails[pitch_id] = MIN ( statcastdetails[pitch_id] ) )
)
```

This one returns the first pitch of the game.

PitchID is a field I've built for pitcher, atbatnumber, and pitchnumber trying to build an index by game and pitcher.

I've built Max and Min Speed with the following formula

```
MaxSpeed = CALCULATE (
    MAX ( statcastdetails[release_speed] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( statcastdetails, statcastdetails[game_pk], statcastdetails[pitcher], statcastdetails[pitch_type] )
)
```

I'm trying to return the release speed for each first and last pitch of each group (game, pitcher, pitch_type in that order)

Below is what I would like to return, columns OpenSpeed and CloseSpeed.  Open will be the first row for each gamepk, pitcher, pitch_type and close will be the last row of the gamepk, pitcher, pitch_type.

There are 3 pitch types for this example.  The second pitch type has only one record, so the open and close should be the same value.

[image]

Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code maybe

```
First transaction date = 
MINX(FILTER('Data','Data'[Value]='Data'[Value]),'Data'[Date].[Date])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).